# Unix awk command BEGIN and END syntax error

Tags: linux, unix

I am not sure what is wrong with my command. Says "Syntax error". I am trying to find the largest number my textfile and print it out.
Here is my code.

```
   awk'{ BEGIN{max=0}
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
   {
   max < $i {max = $i}
   }
   END{print max}}' textfile.txt
```

Here is the error i got

```
   BEGIN{max =0}
   ^ syntax error
   END{print max}
   ^ snytax error.
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
awk '
    BEGIN{max=0}
    {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            if (max < $i) {max = $i}
        }
   }
   END{print max}
' textfile.txt
```

Comment: There's other syntax errors (missing `if` statement)

Answer (score 1):

When you can have letters in your textfile.txt, you want to skip these:

```
grep -Po "\b[0-9]+\b" textfile.txt | sort -rn | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```html
awk' BEGIN{max=0}
   {
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
   {
   max < $i {max = $i}
   }
   }
   END{print max}' textfile.txt
```